# H2 tag width renders different in FF and IE9

Tags: html, css

If you look on the right, http://forensicon.net/blog/ - the width for the sidebar names renders differently in IE9 and FF. I'm not sure why it fills all the way to the right in IE9 even when I explicitly give it a width. I'd like to understand what is causing this behavior so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: It's complicate to accomplish coherent cross-browser rendering when browsers have to use quirks mode. I suggest you use an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fforensicon.net%2Fblog%2F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have a comment before the doctype. This puts IE into quirks mode and it won't attempt to perform like all the other far more modern browsers. Remove everything before the doctype.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is an age-old problem. Different browsers have different defaults for things like header and list tags.

Use a [CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) and explicitly style them the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

There may be different CSS base styles defined by the browser that are causing it to render inconsistently. You might want to consider using a base reset CSS that resets all the styles to a common foundation across browsers, and then lay your custom CSS on top of it.

A very popular one out there is YUI Reset CSS
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/